# Package more than 1 widget in a Android App

Tags: java, android, android-widget

So I've been playing around with android app and widgets. have a few things running. but one thing i cant seem to figure out is how to package more than 1 widget. say i wanted to release my set of widgets?

where in the manifests can i do this?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing a widget you should have something like this in your `AndroidManifest`:

```
<receiver android:name="SomeCoolWidget">
   <intent-filter>
   <action
   android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
   </intent-filter>
   <meta-data
   android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
   android:resource="@xml/something" />
</receiver>
```

Adding a second receiver should do the trick.

Comment: Dun forget to close the question if you have solved it. And best to write a solution as well.